# How can I rebase changes from an upstream branch's parent periodically without it trying to include changes that are already in my branch?

Tags: git, rebase

I created a branch based on my remote "origin/master", and I pushed that new branch to the remote as "origin/tester" (and updated my local branch to merge with that new remote instead of origin/master).

After the master got a few commits that I needed (a new file "testfile" was added), I ran (with my local tester branch checked out):

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
git push origin tester
```

And all was well.  The expected changes were included in my local branch, and the pushed cleanly to the remote origin/tester branch.  Then, more changes were made on both branches (non-conflicting changes in separate files).  So, I did:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

and I get a conflict, saying that both have added "testfile".  This makes me think that, when it did the rebase, it was including all of the changes since origin/tester split from origin/master rather than doing all changes that were made since I last rebased from origin/master.  Am I right about that?  How can I update my branch to get it to do the "right" thing?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the workflow you described, as far as I can tell, though as [Adam mentions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9913900/456814), it would not have been possible to push to `origin/tester` without specifying a force push, unless `origin/tester` didn't contain any commits that `origin/master` didn't already have. If you add information about your log history (with `--graph --oneline` would be nice), we might be able to help you further. You can remove sensitive information from the messages if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

After your initial rebase, the push could not have worked. You would have required the force option (-f or --force).

Based on this inaccuracy in the steps you provided, it does seem like you ended up rebasing work on top of itself.